# want to assign datacolumn with checkbox type to a gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datatable, datacolumn

i have a datagridview and want to add DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
otherwise i have a datatable and want to set it as datasource of my gridview
but cant show my gridview with check box

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn newHeader = new DataColumn();
            newHeader.ColumnName = oldTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();             
            newHeader.DataType =typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn);
            //newHeader.DataType = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            //string newHeader = oldTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            newTable.Columns.Add(newHeader);                
        }
        DataRow accessRow = newTable.NewRow();            
        for (int j = 0; j < oldTable.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            Boolean access =Convert.ToBoolean(oldTable.Rows[j][2]);
            accessRow[j] = access;
            var sklj=  accessRow[j].GetType();
        }
        newTable.Rows.Add(accessRow);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = newTable;
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler than that:

EDIT: I was mistaken: This should do it:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dgchk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgchk);
```

this should be done after you set the DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn newHeader = new DataColumn();
            newHeader.ColumnName = oldTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();             
            newHeader.DataType =typeof(System.Boolean); //Change This Line Like This
           newTable.Columns.Add(newHeader);                
        }
```

Change your code `typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn())` to `typeof(System.Boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add new Column and Row like this...

```
yourTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Selected", typeof(bool)));
yourTable.Rows.Add(false)
```